# Кроссбраузерность. Отступы для Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css

Приветствую. Помогите пожалуйста.
В браузере Mozilla Firefox некорректно отображаются отступы.
Chrome, Opera, Yandex нормально отображают, а тут не очень правильно.

Вендорные префиксы пробовал, не помогло. Пробовал найти ошибку в инспекторе элементов, но не помогло тоже.

Текст не важен, по этому немного его изменил. **Проблема в том, что с Mozilla нижняя строка плывет:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block2,
.block3 {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.block2-all-wrap {
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.block2-col-left,
.block2-col-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  width: 50%;
}

.block2-left-wrap,
.block2-right-wrap {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: -2.5%;
  padding-right: -2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.block2-left-wrap::after,
.block2-right-wrap::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #71069E, #3B52B8, #00A2D4);
  border-radius: 16px;
  bottom: -4px;
  content: '';
  left: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block2-left-wrap:hover::after,
.block2-right-wrap:hover::after {
  //background: linear-gradient(135deg, red 20%, blue 70%);
}

.block2-left-wrap {
  margin-right: -2.5%;
}

.block2-right-wrap {
  margin-left: -2.5%;
}

.block2-col-left-ico,
.block2-col-right-ico,
.block3-col-left-ico,
.block3-col-center-ico,
.block3-col-right-ico {
  font-size: 600%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.block2-col-left-ico-text,
.block2-col-right-ico-text {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 200%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block2-col-left-text,
.block2-col-right-text {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/98212653bc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="block2">
    <div class="block2-all-wrap">
      <div class="block2-col-left wow slideInLeft animated" data-wow-offset="200">
        <div class="block2-left-wrap">
          <div class="block2-col-left-ico">
            <i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="block2-col-left-ico-text">
            Історія
          </div>
          <div class="block2-col-left-text">
            13букв1234567 college як будівельний технікум створений відповідно до постанови Ради Міністрів УРСР №<span class="bold">679</span> від <span class="bold">20.06.1967</span> на базі сільськогосподарського технікуму, який готував фахівців для сільського
            господарства з <span class="bold">1927</span> року. <br><br> Згідно з наказом Державного агропромислового комітету УРСР від <span class="bold">19.12.1990</span> №<span class="bold">249</span> 13букв1234567 будівельний college реорганізований
            у 13букв1234567 будівельно-економічний college. <br><br> Відповідно до наказу Міністерства аграрної політики України від <span class="bold">11.11.2005</span> №<span class="bold">626</span> college реорганізовано у 13букв1234567 будівельно-економічний
            коледж teststsr державного аграрного університету.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block2-col-right wow slideInRight animated" data-wow-offset="200">
        <div class="block2-right-wrap">
          <div class="block2-col-right-ico">
            <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="block2-col-right-ico-text">
            Профіль
          </div>
          <div class="block2-col-right-text">
            До <span class="bold">1981</span> року в будівельному технікумі велась підготовка фахівців лише будівельного напрямку. З <span class="bold">1981</span> року в 13букв1234567 розпочалась підготовка фахівців економічного спрямування – бухгалтерів
            та плановиків для системи Мінсільбуду України, з <span class="bold">1998</span> року – програмістів, з <span class="bold">2003</span> року – фінансистів, а з <span class="bold">2012</span> року - менеджерів. <br> У <span class="bold">1991</span>            році одним із перших на Україні технікум пройшов відповідну перевірку інспекції Міносвіти України і отримав статус закладу II рівня акредитації – коледж, який потім підтвердився ліцензуванням та акредитацією відповідних спеціальностей. В даний
            час підготовка фахівців в коледжі здійснюється за I освітньо-кваліфікаційним рівнем згідно ліцензії Міністерства освіти і науки, молоді та спорту України серія АЕ №<span class="bold">636471</span> видана <span class="bold">10.06.2015</span>            року з шести спеціальностей.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Если в block2-col-left-text  padding сделать 0, то текст вместится в блок, но выглядеть потом будет ужасно.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение немного корявое, но зато быстрое)

Добавьте в css:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .block2-col-left-text,
    .block2-col-right-text{
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
}
```

И регулируйте отступ как угодно.

Comment: О вендорных префиксах слышал, но вот это: @-moz-document url-prefix() - новое для меня. Это все решает. Спасибо! Помогло.